# POSTGRESQL: Create table as Selecting specific type of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with mixed types of data (real, integrer, character ...) but i would only recover columns that have real values.

I can construct this:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY(
select 'o' || '.' || c.column_name 
from information_schema.columns as c
where table_name = 'final_datas'
and c.data_type = 'real'), ',') || ' FROM final_datas as o' As sqlstmt
```

that gives that:

```
"SELECT o.random,o.struct2d_pred2_num,o.pfam_num,o.transmb_num [...] FROM final_datas as o"
```

The i would like to create a table with these columns. Of course, do this, doesn't work:

```
create table table2 as (
SELECT 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY(
select 'o' || '.' || c.column_name 
from information_schema.columns as c
where table_name = 'final_datas'
and c.data_type = 'real'), ',') || ' FROM final_datas as o' As sqlstmt
)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Look into the pg_catalog for this. Run `psql -E`, then `\d final_datas` within it, and you'll see the relevant queries that you need to run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the whole CREATE TABLE statement as dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY(
select 'o' || '.' || c.column_name 
from information_schema.columns as c
where table_name = 'final_datas'
and c.data_type = 'real'), ',') || ' FROM final_datas as o' As sqlstmt
```

The result can be run with `EXECUTE sqlstmt;`